# Using SessionWindows on aggregated data in KafkaStreams (0.11)

Tags: java, aggregate, type-mismatch, apache-kafka-streams

i'm trying to use SessionWindows in my aggregation function in Kafka (0.11) but can not comprehend, why i get errors.

Here is my code-snippet:

```
// defining some values:
public static final Integer SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS = 6000000;
public static final String INTOPIC = "input";
public static final String HOST = "host";

// setting up serdes:
final Serializer<JsonNode> jsonSerializer = new JsonSerializer();
final Deserializer<JsonNode> jsonDeserializer = new JsonDeserializer();
final Serde<JsonNode> jsonSerde = Serdes.serdeFrom(jsonSerializer, jsonDeserializer);

// some more code to build up the streams
KStreamBuilder builder = new KStreamBuilder();
KStream<String, JsonNode> dataStream = builder.stream(Serdes.String(), jsonSerde, INTOPIC);

// constructing the initalMessage ObjectNode:
ObjectNode initialMessage = JsonNodeFactory.instance.objectNode();
initialMessage.put("count", 0);
initialMessage.put("endTime", "");

// transforming data to KGroupedStream<String,JsonNode>
KGroupedStream<String, JsonNode> data = dataStream.map((key, value) ->{return new KeyValue<>(value.get(HOST).asText(), value);  }).groupByKey(Serdes.String(), jsonSerde);

// finally aggregate the data usind SessionWindows
KTable<Windowed<String>, JsonNode> aggregatedData = data.aggregate(
            () -> initialMessage,

            (key, incomingMessage, initialMessage) -> countData(incomingMessage, initialMessage),

            SessionWindows.with(SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS),

            jsonSerde, 

            "aggregated-data");

 private static JsonNode countData(JsonNode incomingMessage, JsonNode initialMessage){
 // some dataprocessing
 }
```

When i change

```
 KTable<Windowed<String>,JsonNode>
```

to

```
 KTable<String, JsonNode>
```

and remove

```
 SessionWindows.with(SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS)
```

from the aggregate function, everything is ok.

If i don't, eclipse tells me for line

```
 KTable<Windowed<String>, JsonNode> aggregatedData = data.aggregate( [...])
```

> The method aggregate(Initializer, Aggregator, Windows, Serde, String) in the type KGroupedStream is not applicable for the arguments (() -> {}, ( key,  incomingMessage,  initialMessage) -> {}, SessionWindows, Serde, String)

and for the line

```
() -> initialMessage
```

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from ObjectNode to VR

and:

```
 (key, incomingMessage, initialMessage) -> countData(incomingMessage, initialMessage),
```

> The method countData(JsonNode, JsonNode) in the type DataWindowed is not applicable for the arguments (JsonNode, VR)

I realy don't see, where the types get lost!
Any hint would be great!

Thx :D

Comment: Is it just a typo `(key.value)` -> `(key, value)` (comma instead of dot) ?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Just fixed it in this post. But it was not the solution.
Do you have any other Idea, how to fix this issue?

Comment: Not from starring at the code. Maybe our example repo helps: https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples We have couple of examples using lambdas.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, @MatthiasJ.Sax
I looked through the examples, but couldn't find anything new, besides that SessionWindows work fine within the count-method. 

I realized though, that aggregate needs a merger, when using SessionWindows!!
D'oh!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realy needed to implement a Merger:

```
Merger<? super String, JsonNode>tmpMerger = new MergerClass<String, JsonNode>();
```

and add it to the aggregate function:

```
KTable<Windowed<String>, JsonNode> aggregatedData = data.aggregate(
        () -> initialMessage,

        (key, incomingMessage, initialMessage) -> countData(incomingMessage, initialMessage),

        tmpMerger,

        SessionWindows.with(SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS),

        jsonSerde, 

        "aggregated-data");
```